# Does "fatherly" mean "of the father"?

Tags: adjectives, phrase-meaning

I found two expressions used quite a few times in a text, which I am translating as:

- *the fatherly house / the fatherly embrace*

and it seems to me that I can use these expressions to mean

- *the house/embrace of the father*

For example

- *The son claimed the share of his inheritance and left the fatherly house as fast as he could.*

[Oxford languages](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03Mxyf8FS-9HFJTuNikcKPV3uURww%3A1608657751803&source=hp&ei=VyviX_jJLpicUvWOl8gK&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAX-I5Z5TlPnEfu6eobetNPCL_Ah6Q1PG2&q=fatherly%20meaning&oq=fatherly&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgDMgcIABDJAxBDMgcIABAUEIcCMgIIADICCAAyBAgAEEMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoJCCMQJxBGEPkBOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoICAAQsQMQgwE6DgguELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoNCAAQsQMQgwEQyQMQQzoICC4QsQMQgwE6BQguELEDOgIILlDkDFjGE2CYK2gAcAB4AIAB5gGIAeIJkgEFMC42LjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab) defines ***fatherly*** as:

> relating to, resembling, or characteristic of a father, especially in being protective and affectionate.

But can it also mean ***possessed by/belonging to the father***? Is it used in standard English with this meaning?

Can adjectives like ***motherly, brotherly, fatherly*** have this possessive meaning?

Comment: It seems like it may have had that meaning to the translator, anyway.

Comment: It sounds weird. Of course context and poetic license would tell us a lot more. What is the full context?

Comment: @Mitch: I have given a full sentence in the body of my question.

Comment: @fev But that's an example -you- made up. I'd like to see it in an original sentence out in the wild. Can you quote or give a link to a sentence you've read authored by a native speaker that uses 'fatherly' as though it is 'of the father'?

Comment: All the early examples in a Google search for "fatherly house" seem to be _either_ translations from various languages hoping that 'fatherly' works here ('relating to' of course is superordinate to 'belonging to' ... this illustrates the limitations of dictionary definitions) _or_ references to one particular painting. I'd say 'fatherly house' is borderline non-standard. // As it stands, your first sentence is wrong and will soon attract downvotes.

Comment: ok, so in English one should rather say "the father's house/the house of the father" and not "fatherly". Correct?

Comment: I would say that "fatherly embrace" is not necessarily an embrace of a father, but rather an embrace like the embrace of a father.  So, see **resembling** in that Oxford definition.

Comment: I was raised catholic so I never put *the* before *father*. It's *their* father, or [child's] father's house. Or *the family home*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the SOED this usage is not possible any more as "house" is not a noun customarily modifiable by "fatherly".

> (SOED) *a.* **1** (obsolete) ancestral
>                     **2** Of or pertaining to a (real or spiritual) father; paternal. Now only of feelings, conduct or character

Comment: I thought the SOED and the OED were totally compatible?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I noticed that myself, there are discrepancies (surprisingly, as "Shorter" should be taken as "abridged").

Comment: Certainly 'obsolete' is damning, 'rare' giving some licence.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the intended meaning of *fatherly* here is *ancestral* or *ancient*, as in

> Adieu, now ye mountains, thou fatherly home. (William Howitt, *The Student-life of Germany* xvi. 316, 1841) [via OED]

The OED marks this meaning as "rare," and I am not surprised that other dictionaries omit it. I can find no examples of this sense of *fatherly* in COHA or Hansard, only in the sense of being like a father.

Comment: I thought the SOED and the OED were totally compatible?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In the 2nd edition (1989), *fatherly* meaning *ancestral* is marked as obsolete, but in the 3rd edition (2016), they have a citation from 2005 and so it is promoted back to "rare." The only sense marked as obsolete in the 3rd edition is *3b. Of a person: Resembling a father in age; venerable*.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how many examples they have to find to 'repromote' words like this. A single example in the Elbonian Dayly Newz?